# Vue App main.js exceeds 8Mb file size causes performance issues

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack-4

Hi a have a Vue and laravel app, when build the app the main.js file is over the 8MB size, this is my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
require("dotenv").config();
require("laravel-mix-alias");



mix
  .js("resources/js/main.js", "public/js")
  .js("resources/js/pages.js", "public/js/pages.js")
  .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [
      tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js"),
      autoprefixer
    ]
  })
  .disableNotifications()
  .browserSync({ proxy: process.env.APP_URL, https: true })
  .alias({
    "@": "/resources/js",
    "~": "/resources/sass"
  });

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.sourceMaps().version();
}
```

And this is the main.js file, here is all the app, the first four imports add a size of 2Mb

```
import "@/bootstrap";
import "@/plugins";
import "@/components";
import "@/layouts";

import Vue from "vue";
import App from "@/App";
import store from "@/store";
import router from "@/router";
import i18n from "@/plugins/i18n";
import VuejsDialog from "vuejs-dialog";
import MoonLoader from "vue-spinner/src/MoonLoader";


// include the default style
import "vuejs-dialog/dist/vuejs-dialog.min.css";

// Tell Vue to install the plugin.
Vue.use(VuejsDialog);
Vue.component("moon-loader", MoonLoader);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/*Vue.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
  Vue.rollbar.error(err);
}*/

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  i18n,
  store,
  router,
  ...App
});
```

When the application was built with web package 4.44.2, this is the resulting file size, as you can see, the size of /js/main.js is more than 8Mb, it is huge.

```
Asset      Size                         Chunks             Chunk Names
                    /css/app.css   706 KiB                       /js/main  [emitted]  /js/main
                     /js/main.js  8.37 MiB                       /js/main  [emitted]  /js/main
                    /js/pages.js   651 KiB                      /js/pages  [emitted]  /js/pages
                            0.js  15.9 KiB                              0  [emitted]
                            1.js  49.1 KiB                              1  [emitted]
                            2.js  49.2 KiB                              2  [emitted]
                            3.js  30.6 KiB                              3  [emitted]
                            4.js  37.3 KiB                              4  [emitted]
                          404.js  7.65 KiB                            404  [emitted]  404
```

What can i do for solve this performance issue?, thanks for your time.

Comment: Related: [How to reduce bundle size in WEBPACK + VUEJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56059883)

Comment: Some other off-site resources that also look promising: [Possible ways to reduce your webpack bundle size | JS SECRETS](https://dev.to/coder_blvck/possible-ways-to-reduce-your-webpack-bundle-size-js-secrets-550) | [How to drastically reduce your bundle size and load time in Vue.js](https://medium.com/shard-labs/how-to-drastically-reduce-your-bundle-size-and-load-time-in-vue-js-54370d513fdf)